# Ubuntu 19.04 how to get rid of Ctrl+Alt+F7

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Can someone please give definite answer to this?
These shortcuts are very common for any developer practically in any ide... I have no idea why it should take more than an hour to search for a way to disable these and nave no result...

Whenever i press this combination (which should find usages in my code) my os goes blank and gets back to life with Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Any help is appreciated. I'm sure i'm not the only one having this issue.

Comment: In most Linux desktop distros, 
`Alt`-`Ctrl`-`Fn` switches the display to virtual screen "n", where 1-6 are plain TTY terminals and 7 is the X-Window/UI one. I assume these key combos are intercepted very early in the event chain and that the UI doesn't see them. Likewise, your graphic screen manager and desktop shell are probably intercepting other `Alt`-`Ctrl` keystrokes. My rather vanilla Eclipse Neon on Ubuntu doesn't define any `Alt`-`Ctrl`-`Fn` key, and hasn't got many `Alt`-`Ctrl`-`anything`.

Comment: every IDE is different and has its own set of shortcuts. Even tab control shortcuts are different between them

Comment: idea has nothing to do with this, why should it be such a pain to get rid of something as simple as a shortcut :|

Comment: Try the methods in the  post [Rebinding/disabling CTRL+ALT+F#](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34158/rebinding-disabling-ctrlaltf) and tell us if one has worked for you (this kind of thing changes between releases).

Answer (score 4):

The following method works for me on Kubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. It should work for you if you're using X (but [I don't expect it to work in Wayland](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/292868/108618)).

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122454/108618) reads:

> You have two different keymaps. One used by your graphical environment (X) and one used by you console.
>
> The first one is configured by `xmodmap` and `setxkbmap`. The second one is configured by `loadkeys`.
>
> You can dump the first one with `xmodmap` and the second one with `dumpkeys`.

The output of `xmodmap -pke` (run it from within your graphical environment) contains something like

```
keycode  73 = F7 F7 F7 F7 F7 F7 XF86Switch_VT_7
```

To do what you want you need to replace `XF86Switch_VT_7` with `F7`. Invoke

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 73 = F7 F7 F7 F7 F7 F7 F7'
```

From now on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> won't switch to VT_7. If you need to switch anyway, you can

- bind `XF86Switch_VT_7` to another keystroke,
- or "transit" through any non-graphical console (e.g. hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>) where `xmodmap` has no jurisdiction and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) switches to VT_7.

In my tests I confirmed I can then bind and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> in VLC. Other GUI applications should be able to use the shortcut as well.

---

I'm on Kubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and I can make the solution permanent by pasting

```
keycode 73 = F7 F7 F7 F7 F7 F7 F7
```

into my `~/.Xmodmap` file. This works because `/etc/X11/Xsession` sources files from `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/`; one of the files is `80kubuntu-xmodmap` which makes `xmodmap` execute `$HOME/.Xmodmap` (if it exists).